# How to Find all the files that were last modified in some particular month in the folder, Lets say March

Tags: unix

How to find all the files that were last modified in some particular month, Lets say March.

Comment: Lets say `find` is the actual command you want.  Type `man find` and you will find all your answers.

Comment: Don't parse `ls` output ! ls is a tool for interactively looking at file information. Its output is formatted for humans and will cause bugs in scripts. Use globs or find instead. Understand why: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: OP didnt say he wanted an automated solution... nor did OP give any language tag - just a unix request.

Comment: That's more reasons to use `find` and not `ls`

Answer (score 2):

```
LANG=C find -printf '%AY %Ab %p\n' | awk '$1=="2013" && $2="Mar"{$1=$2="";print}'
```

And like stated before in the thread, `ls` is a tool for interactively looking at file information. Its output is formatted for humans and will cause bugs in scripts. Use `find` instead. Understand why: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Added year matching...

Answer (score 1):

This is a great command for this problem:

```
find . -mtime +100 -mtime -200
```

In particular, this will find all files modified more than 100 days ago and less than 200 days ago. Modify the numbers accordingly!

Comment: It's difficult with this command to have **only March files** !

Comment: @sputnick I thought he probably meant march of the current year. But that's true. +1 for your answer